# ComboBox does not fill with desired values

Tags: c#, combobox

Sorry for my bad English. I wrote code last night. My program runs successfully but the answer of fill_model is incorrect. It should be field with different model but it shows all models related to a specific brand. Do you have any idea?
here is the code:

```
private void brand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fill_brand_txt();
            fill_model();
            model.Text = "";

        }
        private void fill_brand_txt()
        {
            string cs = "Data Source=192.168.1.20;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=sa;Password=Abc123;";
            string qu = "select id_kind from model where brand_name=@brand1";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qu, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand1", brand.Text);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                rd.Read();
                brand_txt.Text = rd["id_kind"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error :", ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        private void fill_model()
        {
            string cs = "Data Source=192.168.1.20;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=sa;Password=Abc123;";
            string que = "select model_name from model where id_kind=@id";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(que, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", brand_txt.Text);
            con.Open();
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            model.DisplayMember = "model_name";
            model.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean to use the value of `brand_txt.Text` or should it be a different control to read the value from? Incidentally, you should call `con.Dispose()` after `con.Close()`.

Comment: Is `id_kind` the id of your brands?

Comment: Does brand_txt value change is successfull in fill_brand_txt? Does the sql parameter get the desired value in fill_model? Did you debug it?

Comment: yes. it should use value of brand_txt.text to compare id_kind to detect what model should be writen in model combobx.

Comment: I fill my database like this: kind table(id,item_name) which item_name is the name of my stuff like printer or scanner and so on. then I have model(id_kind,brand_name,model_name). id_kind is not unique and is filled with duplicar numbers of id in kind table

Comment: @DornazGhandehari Can you edit your question to show 3 or 4 entries in each database table, an example of the data the user inputs and the expected and actual results?

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved all of your information in a single table and you want to get all of your model_name you can use this SQL command:

```
SELECT model_name FROM model GROUP model_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand. You have the kind table which contains something like

```
{1, "printer"}
{2, "scanner"}
{3, "laptop"}
```

and so on. Then you have a model table where you have something like

```
{3, "HP", "Probook1"}
{3, "HP", "Probook2"}
{1, "Samsung", "mlxxx"}
{2, "HP", "whatever"}
```

and so on.

You enter "HP" in a field, you get "3" from the model table (you read only the first value) in fill_brand_txt() and you select all "laptop" based on this in fill_model().

I think you mixed up something.

If you want all models listed based on brand you entered, then leave out fill_brand_txt and use the following in fill_model:

```
string que = "select model_name from model where brand=@brand";
{...}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", brand.Text);
```